# How can I pretend to be in a certain country during web scraping?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, user-agent

I want to scrape a website, but it should look like I am from a specific (let's say USA for this example) country (to make sure that my results are valid).

I am working in Python (Scrapy). And for scraping, I am using the rotating user agents (see: https://pypi.org/project/scrapy-fake-useragent-fix/).

The user agents are what I need to scrape. But can I use this, in combination with the request to pretend that I am in a specific country?

If there are some possibilities (in scrapy, Python) please let me know. Appreciated!

**Example how I used the User Agents in my script**

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
'scrapy_fake_useragent.middleware.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400,
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to pretent a certain country you need an IP from that country. Unfortunately this is nothing you can configure just by scrapy settings etc. But you could use a proxy service like crawlera:

https://support.scrapinghub.com/support/solutions/articles/22000188398-restricting-crawlera-ips-to-a-specific-region

Note: unfortunalty this service is not free and the cheapest plan is about 25 EUR. There are many other cheaper services available. The reason Crawlera is expensive is that they offer ban detection and only serve good IPs for your chosen domain. I've found them useful for the cost on Amazon and Google. Though on lesser domains a cheaper service with unlimited service would be more suitable.

Comment: Alternatively, you can search for `ip port proxy list` and try using the proxies you find

Comment: @abdusco could be worth a try. Have you made any experiences with those free proxies?

Comment: Thanks @Raphael and @abdusco! So, my scraper will work (on my local pc) for the US, If I activate a US proxy? The user agents don't influence the 'location', right?!

Comment: @abdusco, I found (http://free-proxy.cz/en/proxylist/country/US/all/ping/all). Do you have more information/ an example how I can use them? Many thanks

Comment: @helloworld1990 right, user agent is not language but browser specific. It tells the website what kind of browser you are using or how your bot is called ;) The only header I can think of which might be country related is "accept-language".

Comment: There are many other cheaper services. Crawlera is more expensive because they provide ban detection and only serve you good IPs for the domain. I use them for Amazon and Google projects as its easier than doing my own ban detection. However, lately they have been too slow to use on Amazon.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using Selenium (Don't know about Scrapy), First tell the bot to go to this [site](https://whatismyipaddress.com/) : 
[Proxy Site](https://whatismyipaddress.com/)

And then add your target site to search box and scrape .

Answer (score 0):

```
Hello @helloworld1990,

Based on your requirement, say if you want to make each request using different IPs i.e. use IP Rotation (used when the site is detecting and blocking you after certain requests) then go for "Proxy Providers" there are many such providers you just need to google them.

If its not the case above, then for short term use you can try using TOR IPs. But TOR IPs are well known and are generally blocked. Else, you can still buy few static IPs from Proxy Providers and make the requests.

if(uniqueIpForEachRequestFromDifferentGeoLocations){
//go for proxy providers - IP Rotation
}else{
if(shortTermUse){
//go for tor nodes
}else{
//go for static IPs`enter code here`
}
}

Cheers! Hope this helps..
```